# How can I crop four videos into an unusual aspect ratio, and then stack them all on top of each other?

Tags: video, software

This seems like it would have a solution but I haven't had luck online. I am working on a video project that involves taking subtitles for four videos and then stacking them on top of each other. In order to do this, I need to basically take the bottom 25% of four videos, so that I have four videos that are "slivers", almost like horizontal videos shot on a phone. I'm not sure how to do this cropping, for one.

Second, I need to stack all of these four videos together on top of each other. They would all have the same horizontal and vertical size. I'm not really sure how to do any of this, and would like to do it using only free tools. None of the videos will have audio, as that will be processed separately.

Thank you.

Comment: that sounds very likely to be straightforward using ffmpeg - have a look through our other ffmpeg questions for some guidance.

Comment: What software do you have available to you?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the software you're using.
But here's an example with the free DaVinci Resolve:

First you stack all four images on top of each other.

[image: Four videos stacked on the timeline]

Then you can go to the inspector in the top right and scroll down to cropping.
Here you can crop off the top 3/4. In my case, the height of the video is 2560, that /4*3 = 1920.
[image: Enter Crop Top in Inspector]

now repeat this for all four videos.

Now you can stack the images vertically. You need to do this again in 1/4 increments, so in the inspector, for the first element, you move it up with Position.Y by 640 (2560 pixels timeline height / 4). The second by 2*640 and so on.

[image: Enter Position.Y in inspector]

And now you'll have a video with just the four lower fourths stacked on each other.

Comment: I ended up finding an easy way to do this in kdenlive (you can stack the videos on top of each other and just move the frame up so only part of the video beneath is visible, essentially using picture-in-picture but not the way it was intended), but this looks like a perfect solution thank you for answering.

Comment: That also works as long as it's always the edge piece you want to keep. With the crop you can also use any part, by cropping top and bottom